# A Maze of Characters

Tags: mazes, computer-science

I have a maze here with me. However, this maze is quite hard to see.

```
w
Q
q
#
2
ñ
ÿ
```

The bottom of the list of characters is the start of the maze. The top is the end.

---

Other puzzles in this series of mazes:

- [A Maze of Characters](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/37889/a-maze-of-characters)
- [A Mqze of Miszpeked Worfs](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/37929/a-mqze-of-miszpeked-worfs)

Comment: +1 for the idea. Not the most challenging of puzzles (at least for the audience of *this* site), but a nice one.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Converting these UTF-8 characters to binary gives the below 7x8 array of bits. Since the bottom is all ones, and you said start at the bottom, the intention must be that you can walk along ones while zeroes are walls. The solution is to stay in the third column from the left and head up, except to jog around a zero in the second row from the top.

```
01110111  
01010001  
01110001  
00100011  
00110010  
11110001  
11111111
```

Comment: Was just writing up that if it were this, it's not much of a maze

Comment: There's also another solution to it.

Comment: @Peanut fundamentally different?

Comment: Yes. You can convert the list of characters into another maze.

Answer (score 0):

```
01010111
10011000
10100100
00000010
00100011
01110001
01010001
```

Here one is considered as wall, and this is ASCII conversion to binary.
You need to walk on zeroes from bottom.

Solutions: start from first row from left and walk up straight if blocked turn right and go for one step and again go up straight do the same if got blocked.

Comment: You're missing the *difficult* part of the puzzle: What is the solution *path* through this (*very difficult*) maze? ;c)

Comment: @BmyGuest, Added solution of the puzzle.

Comment: Could you explain how this is ASCII converted to binary? I thought that UTF-8 starts with ASCII as the first 128 characters, and doesn't have ñ or ÿ (maybe extended does?). So shouldn't the top row "w" be the same as the UTF-8 version, for example?

Comment: @JonathanAllan, Yes Its the decimal place equivalent of extended ñ or ÿ

Comment: Jonathan Allan has a point: That's not a proper ASCII conversion. You've got the Q's and the hash mark, but your W is a capital letter and instead of the digit 2 (with ASCII code 50), you've got the unprintable control sequence `STX`. And your letters are out of order. What's labelled as UTF-8 in Mike's answer is really 8-bit extended ASCII with the Latin1 character set. (The y with dieresis is a giveaway: It is 255 in Latin1 and a frequent misinterpretation of the value −1.) The conversion used here is the DOS codepage 437, where ñ is 164 and ÿ is 152.

Comment: hmmm you are correct, should I delete my answer or just keep it as it is.