# A Mqze of Miszpeked Worfs

Tags: english, mazes

I have another maze for you to do. This one is [english](/questions/tagged/english), the last was [computer-puzzles](/questions/tagged/computer-puzzles). But you see, they may look like the opposite of mazes, but you can find a way to enter and exit, and thus win.

```
 exit
 |
qmqzing
vhucken
muggetz
ouxsket
answdrz
douvlef
comlurw
solcemy
    |
enter
```

Here's a version without misspelled words below. This will help but your maze takes place on the above "board".

```
amazing
chicken
nuggets
puzzler
answers
doubled
compute
solvent
```

---

Other puzzles in this series of [mazes](/questions/tagged/mazes):

- [A Maze of Characters](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/37889/a-maze-of-characters) ([computer-puzzles](/questions/tagged/computer-puzzles))
- [A Mqze of Miszpeked Worfs](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/37929/a-mqze-of-miszpeked-worfs) ([english](/questions/tagged/english))

Comment: Okk... So, What exactly are we supposed to do? I mean where to enter, where to exit??

Comment: The bottom is the entrance, the top in the exit. I'll make that more clear.

Comment: This would work a lot better if the correct words weren't provided.. maybe you could clue them in the future?

Comment: The idea for the puzzle is nice, but I have to agree with @Arth that providing both the "maze" **and** the correct words is basically posting a puzzle with its solution next by. :c(  I'm still up-voting the idea, though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Representing a correct character by 1 and an incorrect character by 0 we get:

> ```
> 0101111
> 0101111
> 0111110
> 0100010
> 1111010
> 1110110
> 1110100
> 1110100
> ```
>
> If we assume ones can be navigated as the path, and taking the entrance and exit as column-specific, we can solve the maze by beginning in the 5th column, go up 3, right 1, up 4, left 4, up three and exit.

Comment: It's typically better on this site to hide your answers using the >! tag at the beginning of the line.

Comment: i think the 'enter' and 'exit' marks are column-specific.

Comment: @dcfyj How do you spoiler tag preformatted text?

Comment: Just place >! at the beginning of each line, you can use the preview under your post for guidance. Also you can use two spaces at the end of the line for line breaks.

Comment: ah, I see your dilemna now.

Comment: @MorganG I've spoiler-tagged it for you.  For preformatted text, you need to use the <pre> tag when it's in a spoiler.  I also removed the strikeout text.  People can see previous answers in the edit history if they're interested.

Comment: I rolled back the edit to my answer that was performed by another user. The edit was so significant that I felt the answer no longer represented my work, which I was not comfortable with.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that a solution involves

> traversal of the maze using only correct characters.

There appear to be several solutions, but the most efficient one is

$\require{action}\require{enclose}\toggle{\enclose{roundedbox}{\text{ Click here to show solution }}\\\begin{array}{l}\mathtt{qmqzing}\\\mathtt{vhucken} \\\mathtt{muggetz}\\\mathtt{ouxsket}\\\mathtt{answdrz}\\\mathtt{douvlef}\\\mathtt{comlurw}\\\mathtt{solcemy}\end{array}}{\enclose{roundedbox}{\text{ Click here to hide solution }}\\\begin{array}{l}\mathtt{q}\bbox[cyan]{\mathtt{m}}\mathtt{qzing}\\\mathtt{v}\bbox[cyan]{\mathtt{h}}\mathtt{ucken} \\\mathtt{m}\bbox[cyan]{\mathtt{ugget}}\mathtt{z}\\\mathtt{ouxsk}\bbox[cyan]{\mathtt{e}}\mathtt{t}\\\mathtt{answd}\bbox[cyan]{\mathtt{r}}\mathtt{z}\\\mathtt{douv}\bbox[cyan]{\mathtt{le}}\mathtt{f}\\\mathtt{coml}\bbox[cyan]{\mathtt{u}}\mathtt{rw}\\\mathtt{solc}\bbox[cyan]{\mathtt{e}}\mathtt{my}\end{array}}\endtoggle$

Comment: Explanation why this is correct?

Comment: This was correct, @Reibello, but I accepted the other answer instead.